# Convert Ethereum bytes32 hexadecimal to Solana address format

Tags: type-conversion, ethereum, solana

how can I convert the recipient '0x1d7030efa359a07737d690157e8c4bb853772d33378f0fd3e6601b47ed0f02b5' which is in bytes32 to a string basically it should be a Solana address (Base-58). Not able to figure out the conversion. Thanks!
Transaction hash: [https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf39aed88f313a820c45e35b81defcdb185cc70e755283d6f1b9146fd6b9b8d44[enter](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xf39aed88f313a820c45e35b81defcdb185cc70e755283d6f1b9146fd6b9b8d44%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTCux.png)

I tried using solana-address-codec package, it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

try

`b.toBase58()`

from [this](https://thegraph.com/docs/en/developing/assemblyscript-api/#bytes) library